# Pandas Merging rows with column values within a range of each other

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example dataframe as shown below

```
   x    y   dx
0  1  6.0  1.1
1  2  6.0  1.5
2  2  6.5  1.2
3  3  7.2  4.3
4  4  7.5  4.5
5  4  8.0  4.7
6  5  1.1  7.0
```

I would like to merge the rows if the values in column dx are within a range of 1 of each other. There will be no overlapping ranges. I can either keep one of those rows and drop the rest or take an average of all the rows. So the expected output would look like

```
   x    y   dx
1  1  6.0  1.1
2  3  7.2  4.3
3  5  1.1  7.0
```

or

```
   x     y     dx
0  1.67  6.17  1.26
1  3.67  7.57   4.5
2  5     1.1   7.0
```

Comment: You want any of these 2 options or both of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: @archer Any of the two will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the first option with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
new_df=df[0:1]
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df.dx.iloc[i]-new_df.dx.iloc[-1]>1:
        new_df=pd.concat([new_df, df.iloc[i:i+1,:]], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I have modified the example data frame to correctly reflect the problem. It is not necessary that one row will have all integers.

Comment: So, starting from first row, you want to keep first row and drop all rows in range dx+1 then keep the next row (no matter the value of dx) and drop next rows that have dx+1 from that row, etc?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: i have made some changes, please check my answer

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance. Maybe an upvote too? Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df_final = df.groupby((df.dx.diff().abs() > 1).cumsum(), as_index=False).first()

Out[288]:
   x    y   dx
0  1  6.0  1.1
1  3  7.2  4.3
2  5  1.1  7.0
```